# Is this a bad solution for reversing a linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * } 
 */


public class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        if(head == null){
            return head;
        }
       ListNode temp = new ListNode(head.val);
       head = head.next;
       while(head != null){
           ListNode nxt = new ListNode(head.val);
           nxt.next = temp; 
           temp = nxt;
           head = head.next;
       }
       return temp;
    }
}
```

For reversing a linked list,
this works but I am not satisfied, how can I do better? This seems like a bad solution to be honest, taking up space every loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to [codereview.se]

Comment: "taking up space every loop." so you can re-write it so it doesn't if ListNode is mutable.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.reverse(List<?>)`

if it's not satisfying you check other methods inside this class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not an optimal solution to create and append nodes for reversing a linked list.

Please refer http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/reverse-a-linked-list/. Good explanation is available.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion instead

```
    public void reverse(ListNode prev, ListNode currNode) {
        if (currNode == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            reverse(currNode, currNode.next);
            currNode.next = prev;
        }
    }
```

Now you can call `reverse(null, headNode)` to reverse it in place